# Testing Cerner CCL Query Data with Oracle's Unit Testing Framework

Tags: sql, tdd

I've been looking for a unit-testing framework for Cerner CCL (now with Oracle), and it looks like one does exist here:

https://github.com/cerner/cclunit-framework/blob/main/doc/CCLUNITTESTS.md

For those not familiar, Cerner CCL is structured very similarly to SQL, and also contains report-writing features.

What I'm curious about is how to unit-test query data (result-sets returned with a CCL query). Getting into specifics about the Cerner framework is likely a stretch-goal, but if we can't find an answer there, I wonder how this would typically be done with SQL?

This particular testing framework seems to be geared around subroutines / functions, aka asserting the results of functions. So how would one test a CCL (or SQL) query?

Comment: This might not be well received because it's in the vein of tool recommendations rather than a cut & dried reproducible problem.

Comment: How I've always done unit testing is just having a collection of plain old .sql files with test cases return such that an empty result is a pass. Then using python, ruby, or some other flexible language to orchestrate the tests and prepare reports.